# Tkinter: radio button getting dataset and a function to find matches and mismatches between datasets

Tags: function, tkinter, radio-button

Quite new in Python.
I am trying to create an interface with different radiobuttons.
Each radiobutton gets a dataset.
Two buttons that when are clicked recall two different functions: find matches and mismatches between the datasets selected by the radiobuttons.
the result is printed in a widget.
I really cannot get to work the functions of matching and mismatching.
Can I have help to know how to proceed please?
Best,

```
**from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.title("matches and mismatches")
def matches():
    messagebox.showinfo("function of finding matches")
def mismatches():
    messagebox.showinfo("function of finding mismatches")
Datasetone = ["Michel", "John", "Carol", "Bob", "Justine", 'Harry',]
Datasettwo = ["Justine", "John", "Carol", "Bob", "Josh", "Marcello"]
Radiobutton(root, text='Dataset one').pack()
Radiobutton(root, text='Dataset two').pack()
Matches = Button(root, text='Matches', command=matches).pack()
Mismatches = Button(root, text='Mismatches', command=mismatches).pack()
root.mainloop()**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is example code of how it can be done. It is simple so you can understand it better.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.title("matches and mismatches")

var = tk.IntVar()
var2 = tk.IntVar()


data_set_one = ["Michel", "John", "Carol", "Bob", "Justine", "Harry"]
data_set_two = ["Justine", "John", "Carol", "Bob", "Josh", "Marcello"]

dictionary = [{"id": 1, "data_set": data_set_one}, {"id": 2, "data_set": data_set_two}]


def matches(set1, set2):
    for item in dictionary:
        if item["id"] == set1.get():
            first_set = item["data_set"]
        elif item["id"] == set2.get():
            second_set = item["data_set"]
        else:
            continue
    match = []
    for k in first_set:
        for v in second_set:
            if k == v:
                match.append(k + ',')
    messagebox.showinfo("Matches", message=match)


def mismatches(set1, set2):
    for item in dictionary:
        if item["id"] == set1.get():
            first_set = item["data_set"]
        elif item["id"] == set2.get():
            second_set = item["data_set"]
        else:
            continue
    mismatch = []
    for k in first_set:
        if k not in second_set:
            mismatch.append(k + ',')
    messagebox.showinfo("Mismatches", message=mismatch)


tk.Radiobutton(root, text='Dataset one', variable=var, value=1).pack()
tk.Radiobutton(root, text='Dataset two', variable=var2, value=2).pack()
Matches = tk.Button(root, text='Matches', command=lambda: matches(var, var2)).pack(pady=5)
Mismatches = tk.Button(root, text='Mismatches', command=lambda: mismatches(var, var2)).pack(pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Import is changed from `from tkinter import *` to `import tkinter as tk`.
Two variables `var` and `var2` are created and they are `int` type. After list of `dictionary` is created where every `data_set` is given its `id`.  In `radiobuttons`, `variable` and `value` is added. (for every dataset there is `tk.IntVar()` and value is equal to `id` inside `dictionary`). Two functions, `mismatches`  and `matches` are created and both functions have two `parameters`.
Inside function `matches` we check if `id` inside `dictionary` is equal to selected `radiobutton`, and if it is, variable `first_set` is assigned value of `dictionary` for that item. Empty `list match` is created and inside two `loops` we check if two list have matching items, and if there is matching item, it is added to list `match`. In `messagebox` title is set and message is equal to `match`. In `mismatches` function everything is similar to `matches` function. In `mismatches` 2nd way of getting matches/mismatches is displayed in `for loop`.

Comment: Hi again, what if I want a third radio button for a third list and see if two, or all three lists have words in common? here is what I did and of course does not work. To make it easier I took away the mismatches and work only with matches. I think I started right but I cannot understand how to adjust the function...